# Python import updated library from another directory when parent directory already have old version of that library

Tags: python, linux, path, server, ipython

I am working on a powerful cluster running Red Hat Enterprise Linus - 6+.

I need to import a library (Say Tensorflow) from another directory, but main directory already contains an older version of tensorflow.

Structure -

```
I Don't have Admin privileges for these libraries

Anaconda-directory 
 |--- tensorflow 0.7
 |--- other libraries which I need

Other Directory
 |--- tensorflow 0.11

My Home Directory (I have privileges here)
Local directory of anaconda
 |--- Keras
```

So, I need to use Anaconda-directory, but I want to use updated version of `tensorflow (0.11)`, and I also want to use `Keras`.

I have tried following commands -

```
METHOD - 1
# Load Anaconda module
module load apps/anaconda/4.1.1/gnu
# Has tensorflow 0.7 installed
jupyter notebook
--> Works, but with tensorflow 0.7 (Which is incompatible with keras)

METHOD - 2
# Load new version of tensorflow
# It automatically python module located at compiler/python/2.7.10/compilervars along with CUDAnn and others
module load apps/tensorflow/0.11/gnu

# Point to my local installation of anaconda where I have installed Keras
export PYTHONPATH=/home/-path-to-my-home-dir/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH

echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/-path-to-my-home-dir/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:/home/apps/TENSOR_GPU/0.11/gnu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

--> Works well in python shell, but I want to use IPython Notebook

jupyter notebook
--> Doesn't work in Ipython Notebook, which I guess is due to the reason that it uses jupyter notebook from my home dir (Not an Admin)


###  WHAT I WANT  ###
Anaconda Distribution --> From Server Module Directory (Not my local Directory)
Jypyter --> From above anaconda dist (Not my local anaconda dist)
Tensorflow --> From another module (Newer Version)
Keras --> Installed in my local anaconda distribution

# Any Other additional packages
# either not available on server (I can't install on server)
# or older versions available
# For such libraries, I should be able to use just that package 
# from my home directory (I can have anaconda installed on my home dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this.

- Open a Jupyter notebook.
- `import sys`
- `sys.path[0:0] = ["/path/to/new/tensorflow"]`
- Import tensorflow, check version.
- Import libraries from Anaconda.

The third step can be extended to your taste, to include other things off your normal `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Just tried it
`sys.path[0:0] = ["/home/apps/TENSOR_GPU/0.11/gnu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow"]`
But still using older tensorflow version
`tensorflow.__version__
'0.7.1'`

Comment: `>>> sys.path`
 = 
`['/home/apps/TENSOR_GPU/0.11/gnu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow', '', '/home/apps/TENSOR_GPU/lib/python27.zip', '/home/apps/TENSOR_GPU/lib/python2.7', '/home/apps/TENSOR_GPU/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/apps/TENSOR_GPU/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/apps/TENSOR_GPU/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/apps/TENSOR_GPU/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/apps/TENSOR_GPU/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/apps/TENSOR_GPU/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg', '/home/apps/TENSOR_GPU/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg']`

Comment: I can only suspect that your notebook initialization already imports tensorflow. Does `sys.modules.keys()` include `"tensorflow"` in a freshly open notebook? BTW try `reload("tensorflow")`; maybe it will reload it from a new path. (Not that I'd like such an approach.)